# Why Vue.js needs to be add in the body tag

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I added my vue.js in the header but it has an error that says **element root can't be found**, because I have a div with an id of **root**.

But when I add it on the body everything works fine.

This is my js code.

```
new Vue({
     el: '#root'
});
```

And this is my html.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
 
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.1.3/dist/vue.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="root">

    <task-list>


    </task-list>


</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you give me a sample of your html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi I didn't see any included js(except for vue package) in your html. But I think the solution is to place your script in footer.

Also if that doesnt work place it inside `window.onload`

```
window.onload = function() {
    new Vue({
        el: '#root'
    });
};
```

Answer (score 7):

you need to import your vue js library at the bottom part of your body because your #app HTML container needs to be loaded first before it can be analysed by vue js.

`<body>`

```
<div id="app">
</div>
<script src="vue.js"></script>
```

`</body>`

Answer (score 0):

you could also use the defer attribute on your script, this will make sure the entire page is loaded before processing the Javascript.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.1.3/dist/vue.js" defer ></script>
    <!-- Assuming that you saved your vue code in a seperate file called vue.js -->
    <script src="vue.js" defer ></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="root">

    <task-list>


    </task-list>


</div>


</body>
</html>
```